# Add a message in experience editor if datasource is not selected for a component in toolbox SXA

Tags: sxa, experience-editor, visual-studio

I need to add a message stating "Select the data source" in `Experience Editor` programmatically for `Content Authors` when the data source is null or the model is empty. I'm using the `SXA Toolbox` to drag & drop the components (`Custom Controller Rendering`) in the respective placeholders.

[image]
Please note: For the custom rendering, I'm not allowed to set the `Datasource location and template` in `Sitecore`.

Code in `.cshtml` file in `Visual Studio` at present.

```
@if (Model.DataSourceItem == null)
 {
    return;
 }
```

Can anyone help with this approach?

Comment: If you clone an existing Sitecore SXA Rendering (e.g Promo Component) while creating your custom rendering, you should get the "No Data source selected" out of the box

Comment: Do you want this for all the OOTB components or only for the custom components?

Comment: @SumitBhatia for all the components not just custom ones.

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay Is it possible to do for custom controller rendering?